# How do I do an exclusive checkout in SVN?

Tags: svn, locking, svn-checkout

I'm looking for a way to make an exclusive checkout from SVN.

1. Is there a way to automatically lock a file when it's being checked out ?
2. If one user makes an exclusive checkout, and then another user makes a checkout to the same file, how do I generate some sort of notification or an instant message to the 2nd user that the file is locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your follow-up posts, what I think you really want is to make sure that people *know* about locks. I'm imagining a case where users A and B have *already* checked out a jpeg. User A now locks it, and you want to make sure that user B knows, so that he or she doesn't begin editing the jpeg and wasting time and effort.

If that's correct, I recommend two things: first and foremost, communication (not very technical, but very powerful when used consistently); second, you might take a look at the `post-lock` repository hook for `svn`. You can use that to have emails sent when someone puts a lock on a file.

From [the `subversion` book](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-lock.html):

> The `post-lock` hook runs after one or more paths have been locked. It is typically used to send email notification of the lock event.

Comment: If you follow that logic and process (e.g. an image file must always be locked before editing), you will not get into the problem!  When you try to lock the file it will warn you that a lock (and reason for the lock) is already in place.  If you use the svn:needs-lock property it enforces a lock policy on that file or type of file

Comment: In your example, if User B tries to edit the jpeg without placing a lock then he/she is not following process

Answer (score 22):

You can add the property or auto-prop `svn:needs-lock` which makes the file read-only and requires you to place a lock on the file to edit it.

If you are using TortoiseSVN you will see a different icon for locked files, this should be easy for a second user to see and know not to edit the file.

[Referenced in TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [svn lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.lock.html) to prevent other users checking changes back in (note that you can use `--force` to take a lock from another user). This will generate messages on the command line telling people who's locked that file.

It's **not** common to do this. People work with SVN by checking out copies (non-exclusively) and writing back changes which are merged with other changes (this occurs for mergeable formats like text - you can't do this for binaries and a checkin will be rejected if another checkin has occurred in the meantime).

I would not expect this to be used regularly, and I normally rely on a) svn's merging capability b) communication with other team members to ensure I'm not treading on other people's toes.

Comment: I agree that communication is the better first choice, but just one note: if you are the administrator of the repo, you can make locks stronger by using the `pre-unlock` repository hook. I'm not really recommending it for normal use, but I can imagine cases where it might be useful or necessary.