# svn scripts to lock files when editing

Tags: svn, locking

I want to lock my repository so that if any file is edited it needs to get svnlock on itself to do so.
I have done this with svn-lock on every file, but I dont have a script to add this to new files and ensure its still on the file next time its committed.

I wondered if there are scripts i can use in the svnserver to setup and ensure these are there always in my repository?

I have looked around stackoverflow and googled, many pages but i cant find a simple script that i understand to do this.
and i dont want to just copy and paste a script just in case its malicious.

can you surggest scripts or better yet detail them here so i understand and can implement this properly please.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184316/761095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of `svn:needs-lock` property? Please check the [Lock Communication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.lock-communication) chapter of the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for the details. You can set the property recursively on your repository and users will be prompted to lock a file before they can modify it.

> Subversion's solution to this problem is to provide **a mechanism to
>   remind users that a file ought to be locked before the editing begins**.
>   The mechanism is a special property: svn:needs-lock. If that property
>   is attached to a file (regardless of its value, which is irrelevant),
>   Subversion will try to use filesystem-level permissions to make the
>   file read-only—unless, of course, the user has explicitly locked the
>   file. When a lock token is present (as a result of using svn lock),
>   the file becomes read/write. When the lock is released, the file
>   becomes read-only again.

Comment: I was looking for a script that handled these for me, as the svnlock needs adding to new files, and to be kept on old files.

We have decided to remove it anyway as it was causing more issues than solving so thanks for the help.